# PHP create table then allow user to click button getting information from table

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I have created a HTML page and it uses PHP to take data from a database and store it into the table created. How can I get it so when the user clicks a button it will preform a certain task according to the row in the table using php?

I am wanting to take information from a database and create new rows in a HTML table. In those rows will be data from the database, there's also a button on each row. When the user clicks that button I want it to call a function using the specified 'name' which is represented by the variable $nam.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    $deny = array("222.222.222", "333.333.333");
    if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
       header("location: http://www.google.com/");
       exit();
    }
    $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.py69.esy.es"); ?>
    <head>
        <title>ServiceCoin</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/home/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h3>Welcome, <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?>. You Currently Have <span id="services"><?php echo $userRow['userServices']; ?></span> Services</h3>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <button onclick="send_coins()" class="button">Send Coins</button>
        <button onclick="create_service()" class="button">Create A Service</button>
        <button onclick="send_coins()" class="button">My Services</button>
        <h3>View Services</h3>
        <span><?php 
        $users = 1;
        $num = 1;
        echo "<center><table width=1000><th>Buy</th><th>Service Name</th><th>Service Cost</th><th>Service Description</th><th>Service Provider Name</th>";
        while($users < 100 && $num < 100){
            $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$users);
            $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
            $id = 0;
            while($id != 10){
                $id = $id + 1;
                if($userRow['userService'.$id] === 'null'){
                }else if(!empty($userRow['userService'.$id])){
                    echo "<tr><td name=$num ><input type=submit value=buy ></td><td class=services width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userService'.$id]."</td><td class=services width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id]."</td><td class=services class=services width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceDes'.$id]."<td class=services width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceName'.$id]."</tr>";
                    //echo $id."Error: ".$con->error;
                    $num = $num + 1;
                    $id = $id + 1;
                }
            }
            $users = $users + 1;
        }
        echo "All Services Loaded";
        echo "</table></center>";
        ?></span>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $msg; ?></span>
        </center>
    </body>
    <script lang="text/javascript" src="scripts/home/index.js"></script>    
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: That's pretty broad, but essentially it sounds like what you're looking to do is create forms in the table rows and put submit buttons in those forms.  Submitting a form would call a PHP page and supply it with the data from that form, and that PHP page would do whatever it is you're looking to do with that data.

Comment: do you want to use javascript to initiate the `task` or simple form submission?

Comment: Yes, as you said that it's broad I will now update it trying to put as much information as possable

Comment: I am mainly wanting to use php as I will be communicating with the database

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot call PHP functions on a user action without using something called [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). This is because once the HTML code is supplied to the user's web browser it is client side and clicking buttons won't allow you to request info from the server (unless it's new pages) unless you call the php file containing the function code through Javascript (using Ajax).

For example, create a "functions.js" file and insert the following code:

```
function FuncName(NameOfRow){
                $.post('phpfunctionfile.php', {NameOfRow: NameOfRow}, function(data) { 
                     if(data==1){
                         //Some sort of code, maybe display a modal with some sort of control panel to do something.
                     }
                }
}
```

Then in the php file code your function and echo back whatever you want as the variable "data" (echo $data;). Of course you can redirect to new pages etc in this file (I have never tried it before though it should work).

Now in the originaly code assuming you are calling each function depending on userServiceName'.$id if that's unique key in your table you want to call your Javascript function using this value as the parameter. I haven't tested the following code and I'm not sure if it's actually what you want, but you should get the idea from the following code and then be able to adapt it for what you are creating.

```
echo "<tr><td name=$num onClick="FuncName('".$userRow['userServiceName'.$id]."' ><input type=submit value=buy ></td><td class=services width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userService'.$id]."</td><td class=services width=250 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceCost'.$id]."</td><td class=services class=services width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceDes'.$id]."<td class=services width=500 align=center>".$userRow['userServiceName'.$id]."</tr>";
```

If this isn't a clear enough explanation please say so. I'll happily provide you some of my code that will better show how I've done it before.